# JavaScript doesn't work on localhost

Tags: javascript, character

First, excuse me if my English is not completely right, as I am Dutch.

I'm busy working on a project. Since a short time, I get some errors in my console when I'm checking the website on my localhost. I'm using USB Webserver, but I had the same problem when I was using WAMP.

The strangest thing is, that the website is working on my live server, without errors.

The errors I get in my console on localhost are:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
- Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I know that, according to the second error, it might be a problem with the order in which the files are placed, but I have done that in the way it was done by the creators of my template.

The only thing I have done, is combining all the JavaScript files and minify them.

When I go to the source code on my live server, there's nothing wrong with the JavaScript code. But when I open the source code on my localhost, I get wrong symbols in the code, that's breaking up the actual code.

One line:
retÀ‚ã����À‚ã��������������������P‡Ê������������`ŸÊ����(ƒã������������à‚ã�����@������à‚ã������������idden"

The charset in my html is set to utf-8. I hope you guys can help me out! :)

If you need more information, just let me know.

Comment: Sounds like somethiing went wrong when you minified your code.

Comment: But why does it still work on my live server? You can check out https://www.cashbackshop.eu, it uses the same minified JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Well,the first error in your console is exactly indicating that somewhere in your code has **a syntax error**.
You said your "html is set to utf-8",you might put the javascript code in the html.**Make a try** to separate it into a single file.